# nodejs + expresssjs + passportjs + mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

login signup and authentication is working good but i just try to store leave application data means which is simple text which is input by user. i wanted to store current login username and typed leave application in db mysql and show to user (frontend).

```
//App.js

        var express = require('express');
        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
        var session = require('express-session');
        var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
        var ejs = require('ejs');
        var path = require('path');
        var passport = require('passport');
        var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;


        // custom libraries
        // routes
        var route = require('./route');
        // model
        var Model = require('./model');

        var app = express();

        passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
           new Model.User({username: username}).fetch().then(function(data) {
              var user = data;
              if(user === null) {
                 return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
              } else {
                 user = data.toJSON();
                 if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
                 } else {
                    return done(null, user);
                 }
              }
           });
        }));

        passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
          done(null, user.username);
        });

        passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
           new Model.User({username: username}).fetch().then(function(user) {
              done(null, user);
           });
        });

        app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
        app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
        app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

        app.use(cookieParser());
        //app.use(bodyParser());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        //app.use(session({secret: 'secret strategic xxzzz code'}));
        app.use(session({ secret: 'secret strategic xxzzz code', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session());

        // GET
        app.get('/', route.index);

        // signin
        // GET
        app.get('/signin', route.signIn);
        // POST
        app.post('/signin', route.signInPost);

        // signup
        // GET
        app.get('/signup', route.signUp);
        // POST
        app.post('/signup', route.signUpPost);

        // logout
        // GET
        app.get('/signout', route.signOut);

        // app.get('/Data', route.data);





        // 404 not found
        app.use(route.notFound404);

        var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(err) {
           if(err) throw err;

           var message = 'Server is running @ http://localhost:' + server.address().port;
           console.log(message);
        });
```

And

```
//route.js

  var passport = require('passport');
  var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

  // custom library
  // model
  var Model = require('./model');

  // index
  var index = function(req, res, next) {
     if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.redirect('/signin');
     } else {

        var user = req.user;

        if(user !== undefined) {
           user = user.toJSON();
        }
        res.render('index', {title: 'Home', user: user});
     }
  };

  // sign in
  // GET
  var signIn = function(req, res, next) {
     if(req.isAuthenticated()) res.redirect('/');
     res.render('signin', {title: 'Sign In'});
  };

  // sign in
  // POST
  var signInPost = function(req, res, next) {
     passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                            failureRedirect: '/signin'}, function(err, user, info) {
        if(err) {
           return res.render('signin', {title: 'Sign In', errorMessage: err.message});
        } 

        if(!user) {
           return res.render('signin', {title: 'Sign In', errorMessage: info.message});
        }
        return req.logIn(user, function(err) {
           if(err) {
              return res.render('signin', {title: 'Sign In', errorMessage: err.message});
           } else {
              return res.redirect('/');
           }
        });
     })(req, res, next);
  };

  // sign up
  // GET
  var signUp = function(req, res, next) {
     if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.redirect('/');
     } else {
        res.render('signup', {title: 'Sign Up'});
     }
  };

  // sign up
  // POST
  var signUpPost = function(req, res, next) {
     var user = req.body;
     var usernamePromise = null;
     usernamePromise = new Model.User({username: user.username}).fetch();

     return usernamePromise.then(function(model) { 
        if(model) {
           res.render('signup', {title: 'signup', errorMessage: 'username already exists'});
        } else {

           var password = user.password;
           var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);

           var signUpUser = new Model.User({username: user.username, password: hash});

           signUpUser.save().then(function(model) {
              // sign in the newly registered user
              signInPost(req, res, next);
           });    
        }
     });
  };

  // sign out
  var signOut = function(req, res, next) {
     if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        notFound404(req, res, next);
     } else {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/signin');
     }
  };


  var data = function(req, res, next){
       if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        notFound404(req, res, next);
     } else {
        var leavedata  = req.body;
        console.log (leavedata);
              var userdataPromise = null;
              // userdata = new Model.UserData({leavedata: leavedataa.leavedata}).fetch();



              // return userdata.then(function (model) {
                  var userleavedata = new Model.UserDataPromise({username: 'admin', leavedata: leavedata.leavedata });

                  userleavedata.save().then(function(model){
                    signin(req, res, next);

                  });
              // });

      }

  };





  // 404 not found
  var notFound404 = function(req, res, next) {
     res.status(404);
     res.render('404', {title: '404 Not Found'});
  };





  // export functions

  // index
  module.exports.index = index;

  // sigin in
  // GET
  module.exports.signIn = signIn;
  // POST
  module.exports.signInPost = signInPost;

  // sign up
  // GET
  module.exports.signUp = signUp;
  // POST
  module.exports.signUpPost = signUpPost;

  // sign out
  module.exports.signOut = signOut;

  // 404 not found
  module.exports.notFound404 = notFound404;
```

And db.js

```
//db.js
    var knex = require('knex')({
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: {
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '1234',
            database: 'employee',
            charset  : 'utf8'
        }
    });

    var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

    module.exports.DB = Bookshelf;
```

And model.js

```
//model.js

var DB = require('./db').DB;

var User = DB.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'tblUsers',

   idAttribute: 'userId'
});


var UserData = DB.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'leave_data',
});


module.exports = {
   User: User,
   UserData: UserData
};
```

And sechema.sql

```
//schema.sql

create database if not exists dbUsers;

use dbUsers;

drop table if exists tblUsers;

create table if not exists tblUsers(
userId integer primary key auto_increment,
username varchar(100) unique,
password varchar(100)
)engine=innodb; 

create table if not exists leave_data(
username varchar(100),
leavedata varchar(500)
)engine=innodb;
```

And Views

```
//signin.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
</head>


<style type="text/css">
 img{
  width: 100%;
 }

 h2{
  padding: 0 596px;
 }

 form{
  margin-left: 561px;
 }



</style>
<body>
  <div class = "header">

    <img src="http://www.face-9.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/railway-
   banner.jpg">
     </div>
  <h2>Sign In Form</h2>
  <form method="post" action="/signin">

     <% if(typeof(errorMessage) !== 'undefined') {%>
        <span><%= errorMessage %></span>
     <% } %>
     <p>
        <label for="username">username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"
           placeholder="username" required="true"/>
     </p>
     <p>
        <label for="password">password</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password"
           placeholder="password" required="true"/>
     </p>
     <p>
        <input type="submit" name="signin" id="signin" value="sign in"/> 
        <a href="/signup" title="register">register</a>
     </p>

  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

view- signup.ejs

```
//signup.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <title><%= title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h2>Register Form</h2>
     <form method="post" action="/signup">
        <% if(typeof(errorMessage) !== 'undefined') {%>
        <span><%= errorMessage %></span>
        <% } %>
        <p>
           <label for="username">username</label>
           <input type="text" name="username" id="username"
              placeholder="username" required="true"/>
        </p>
        <p>
           <label for="password">password</label>
           <input type="text" name="password" id="password"
              placeholder="password" required="true"/>
        </p>
        <p>
           <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" value="register"/>
           <a href="/signin" title="sign in">sign in</a>
        </p>
     </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

view- index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class = "header">

        <img src="http://www.face-9.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/railway-
          banner.jpg">
    </div>



  <p>
     Welcome <strong><%= user.username %></strong>
     <a href="/signout" title="sign out">sign out</a>

  </p>

  <form method="post" action="/"> 


        <p>
            <label for="leavedata">write your leave application here</label>
            <input type="text" name="leavedata" id="leavedata"
            placeholder="leavedata" required="true"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name= "Data" id="Data" value="submit">
        </p>
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i just wanted to store simple leave application and current logined username in database and show in frontend for approval or rejection .